# Setting SKLabelNode font colour appears to be broken in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ios9, uicolor, sklabelnode

Since the iOS 9 update, setting an SKLabelNode's font colour appears to be broken. Calling this sets text to green!

```
SKLabelNode *labelNode = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:GameFont];
[labelNode setFontColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

And setting it to `[UIColor whiteColor]` turns it yellow... The only way to get white text is to not set the colour at all.

I've tried:

```
labelNode.color = [UIColor blackColor];
labelNode.colorBlendFactor = 1;
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. Anyone else having this problem?

Cheers.

Comment: Is `GameFont` a custom font? Try to test changing your font color with a fresh SpriteKit project.

Comment: GameFont was a custom font, but I've tried it with @"Arial" and it's still the wrong colour...

Comment: I have no problem to set font color with a new project.

Comment: Ok, so this is an issue for projects that have upgraded from Xcode 6? I have found other issues, like flipped nodes, but I can't simply create a new project...

Comment: You needn't start a new project, just comment some other code or separate the code that does the font setting in order to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. It seems that for some reason, certain UIColor methods are just returning the wrong values in iOS9. By using RGB values, it comes out correctly.

```
[labelNode setFontColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
```

I'm not sure why [UIColor blackColor] apparently works in a new project though...